# Submitting pyspark job through livy using user defined parameters

Tags: python, pyspark, livy

Our simple post request to `livy` for a self contained `pyspark` module works fine. However, we have reusable components being used by multiple `pyspark` modules. Moreover we have all our code being triggered from the `main.py` module using `--job` argument.

Below is the folder structure:

```
main.py
jobs.zip
     jobs
          job1
              __init__.py
          job2
              __init__.py
```

The following `spark-submit` command works fine. However we are trying to figure out how to pass the `--job` argument using `livy api`.

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--py-files jobs.zip \
src/main.py \
--job value1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the REST API to **/batches** end point, with the bellow sample JSON,

`{"file":"Path to File containing the application to execute","args":["--job","value1"],"pyFiles":[List of Python files to be used in this session]}`

Refer : https://livy.incubator.apache.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html